# Difference between "wants to be you" and "wants to become you"

Tags: meaning, expressions

I've been watching the latest season of House of Cards and in the latest episode I saw there is a line that I think is supposed to convey an image, but I can't quite understand it.
It is about the US president in an election and the family of his opponent. It goes like this:

> The Conways are everything everyone wants to be, You are what everyone
>   wants to become.

So, what is the difference between the **"be"** and **"become"** here?

Answer (score 1):

"I want to become" implies that I am not yet, but that change is needed, and that I want to put effort to achieve the change.

"I want to be a millionaire" - and I want a pony, and our chances our about the same.

"I want to become a millionaire" - you know you will have to work hard to achieve that, right?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. You're saying the difference between the two is that the "become" version implies more intent?